# MVC: search controller tries to find exact match pages, redirecting to them, otherwise it redirects to search results view

Tags: database, search, redirect, model-view-controller

In an MVC application, I'm implementing my search controller (`/search/all/query`) like this:

1. It checks if there are exact match pages of various types for the query, redirecting to them if so (e.g. `/some-other-controller/view/query`).
2. If there are no exact matches, it redirects to a search results page listing possible options (`/search/results/query`) via a union database query.

This works quite nicely, but I feel it is 'wrong' because:

1. In the case of an exact match, I'm making at least one DB query to know about the exact match, then another DB query from that controller to actually produce that view.
2. In the case of no exact matches, it makes several DB queries to determine that there is no exact match, then makes another query for the `search/results/` function/view

I'm concerned that this solution, which focuses on redirects, is clumsy / inefficient because it does some work, then 'passes the buck' to another part of the app that has to do overlapping work.

My questions:

1. Are redirects as described above actually a sensible solution to this situation?
2. Is there a better way of approaching this situation?

Comment: why do you need 2 controllers for this? 
/search/all/query and /search/results/query?
I'd combine those two into one.

Comment: Thanks, that would be an improvement actually. Just to clarify:

Search is one controller. Search/all doesn't load any views, it always redirects to something else, either other controllers if there are exact matches, or the search/results view.

So you're suggesting I have 'search' load a view when there are no exact matches, and redirect to another controller if there are exact matches?

Comment: yes. if /search finds an exact match it can redirect, if there are more than one it loads the view with the current result set and the DB doesn't need to be hit again.